# Proving Big-O Sum Rule?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, proof

I am unsure how to formally prove the Big O Rule of Sums, i.e.:

```
f1(n) + f2(n) is O(max(g1(n)),g2(n))
```

So far, I have supposed the following in my effort:

Let there be two constants `c1` and `c2` such that `c2 > c1`. By Big O definition:

```
f1(n) <= c1g1(n) and f2(n) <= c2g2(n)
```

How should I proceed? Is it reasonable to introduce numerical substitutions for the variables at this step to prove the relationship? Not knowing `g` or `f`, that is the only way I can think to approach.

Comment: There must be loads of solutions on the search engines - is this one? http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?378861-quot-Sum-of-Rules-quot-for-Big-Oh-PROOF

Comment: I had already reviewed Google, and that thread in particular, but it seemed more of an attack on semantics than anything. I did not find anything helpful. The limit approach suggested below makes sense to me, so I will attempt that.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really on topic here, but there's already an answer, so clearly there's some interest in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

```
gmax = max(g1, g2), and gmin = min(g1, g2).
```

gmin is O(gmax). Now, using the definition:

```
gmin(n) <= c*gmax(n) for n > some k
```

Adding gmax(n) to each side gives:

```
gmin(n) + gmax(n) <= c*gmax(n) + gmax(n) for n > some k
gmin(n) + gmax(n) <= (c+1)*gmax(n)       for n > some k
g1(n) + g2(n) <= c'*gmax(n)              for n > some k
```

So we have g1+g2 is O(max(g1, g2)).

Since f1+f2 is O(g1+g2), the transitive property of big-O gives us f1+f2 is O(max(g1, g2)). QED.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I might be more of a constructivist, I'd attack the problem like this:

By the definition of Big-O, there exist positive c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, N<sub>1</sub>, and N<sub>2</sub> such that

> f<sub>1</sub>(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>g<sub>1</sub>(n) for all n > N<sub>1</sub>
>
> and
>
> f<sub>2</sub>(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>g<sub>2</sub>(n) for all n > N<sub>2</sub>

Let:

> N' = max(N<sub>1</sub>,N<sub>2</sub>)
>   c' = c<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>
>   **g'(n) = max(g<sub>1</sub>(n),g<sub>2</sub>(n))**

Then for all n > N' we have:

> f<sub>1</sub>(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>g<sub>1</sub>(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>g'(n)
>   f<sub>2</sub>(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>g<sub>2</sub>(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>g'(n)
>   f<sub>1</sub>(n) + f<sub>2</sub>(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>g'(n) + c<sub>2</sub>g'(n) = c'g'(n)

Therefore, f<sub>1</sub>(n) + f<sub>2</sub>(n) is O(g'(n)) = O(max(g<sub>1</sub>(n),g<sub>2</sub>(n)))

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the definition - just divide both sides by the faster-growing function, take the limit in infinity, and the slower-growing function will approach zero (i. e. it's insignificant).

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense! A limit is not something I thought to include, but it does make perfect sense! Thanks!

EDIT: Actually, is that acceptable, since it is not an equation in the strict sense, but rather an element of a set, and thus does not have "two sides"?