# Is O(n) + O(n log n) equals to O(n log n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

One code I've done follows this schema:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){ // O(N)
    //do some processing...
}

sort(array, array + N); // O(N log N)
```

Whats the complexity in Big-O notation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, yes. nlog n grows stronger than n, so it dominates the overall growth.

Comment: You would be able to answer this question yourself if you go back and review the definition of big-O. Now, if you go back and are still stuck, then we can lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I understand of big-O,

```
O(x+y) = O(max(x,y))
```

Therefore,

```
O(n + n log n) = O(n log n)
```

Comment: And just to be clear, O notation doesn't tell you how absolutely fast something is, just what to expect as `n` gets really really big.

Comment: Proof of the Big-O sum rule: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749784/proving-big-o-sum-rule/16750079#16750079

Comment: So for regular dfs algorithm  using adjacency list time complexity is O(v+E)  will be equal to O(E)?